# Prove that the elements of the dual frame of an IC POVM cannot be positive

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I've read a claim about POVMs in my lecture notes, which I fail to prove. Hence, I would be grateful if some of you have some hints for me /can help me.

Let $\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ be an informationally complete POVM on $Herm(V)$, where $V$ is a Hilbert space. We define its dual frame $\{D_j\}_{j=1}^{d^2}$ by requiring $Tr[N_i D_j] = \delta_{ij}$. The claim is that at least one of the $D_j$'s is not positive.

Well, we know that $\forall i \in\{1,...,d^2\}: ~ N_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} N_i = I$. Furthermore, as we said that we deal with an IC POVM,  we have $\text{Span}\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2} = \mathcal{L}(V)$ and we have the dual-frame condition $Tr[N_i D_j] = \delta_{ij}$. In addition, as the dimension of $\text{Herm}(V)$ equals $d^2$, we know that $\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ is a basis.

I tried to find an argument, why we find at least one $k \in\{1,...,d^2\}$ such that $D_k$ is not positive semi-definite, i.e. has at least one negative eigenvalue. But this turned out to be not very constructive...

Alternatively, I tried to construct a contradition by assuming that both $\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ and $\{D_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ are positive, but (as you might have guessed, as I am asking this question here) I failed to prove it that way.

Is anyone having an idea how I can prove this statement?

Thank you in advance four your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $D_k \geq 0$ for all $k$. Notice that all the $D$ operators have unit trace.

For two PSD matrices it holds that, $Tr(AB) \leq Tr(A)Tr(B)$.
This implies that, $Tr(N_k D_k) \leq Tr(N_k)$ for all $k$

Now we know that $Tr(N_k D_k) = 1$. So if all the dual operators were PSD, we would have the $Tr(N_k) \geq 1$ for all $k$.

This clearly contradicts the POVM property $\sum_i N_i = I$. We can see this by taking trace on both sides. The RHS has trace $d$, while the LHS would have a trace of at least $d^2$

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your answer! I wasn't aware of that trace inequality (or at least I didn't recall it).